# Problemas al trabajar con archivos en Python

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python a través de un manual (Python Crash Course para referencias) y me he encontrado con algunos problemas a la hora de probar pequeños programas de práctica relacionados con archivos externos.

El primer problema es el siguiente: El manual dice que con la función open() puedo simplemente escribir el nombre del archivo que quiero abrir siempre y cuando este se encuentre en el mismo directorio del programa que se está ejecutando, ya que es una ruta relativa. Sin embargo al ejecutar el programa, arroja un error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'in_python.txt'". El archivo se llama in_python.txt y lo alojé en una variable llamada path. Me aseguré de que estuviera en la misma carpeta que el programa, pero no funcionaba. Al final no encontré el problema y tuve que utilizar una ruta absoluta. Para referencia, el código que utilicé se ve así:

```
path = 'c:/Users/.../.../.../.../.../.../chapter_10/in_python.txt'
with open(path) as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
    print(contents.strip())
```

El segundo problema fue el más frustrante: El manual dice que al usar la función open() en modo write, si no existe un archivo con el mismo nombre en la carpeta, python lo creará automáticamente antes de proceder a escribir. Dicho esto, intenté ejecutar este código:

```
guest_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
filename = 'guest.txt'
with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
    file_object.write(guest_name)

with open(filename) as file_object:
    file_object.read()
```

Luego de escribir mi nombre cuando la terminal lo pidió, el programa terminó. La parte de leer el archivo que puse como comprobación no se ejecutó y el archivo no se creó. Creé el archivo manualmente para ver si eso hacía alguna diferencia, pero no pasó nada. Abrí el archivo guest.txt manualmente luego de volver a ejecutar el programa pero estaba vacío. Alguien sabe por qué estas funciones no funcionan correctamente, o al menos, no como lo plantea en el manual?
Muchas gracias de antemano y me disculpo por mi ignorancia.

Comment: Hiciste un read() sobre el archivo, pero no asignaste lo leido a ninguna variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Me aseguré de que estuviera en la misma carpeta que el programa, pero no funcionaba.

Esto es raro, pero creo debe de darse debido a que tu script no está viculado con el directorio que contiene el archivo. Como digo, **es muy raro**, pero puedes vicularlo manualmente desde el mismo script mientras efectivamente estén ambos (el script y el archivo) en el mismo directorio.

```
from os import path

directorio = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
archivo = path.join(directorio,"texto.txt")

with open(archivo,"w") as file:
    file.read()
```

*Puedes leer sobre el modulo os en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)*

> Luego de escribir mi nombre cuando la terminal lo pidió, el programa terminó.

Viendo tu código no veo por que esperarías que te mostrara algo más. Tanto los métodos `.read()` como `.write()` ninguno muestra nada por pantalla. Si quieres ver algo puedes hacer

```
print(file_object.read())
```

> Abrí el archivo guest.txt manualmente luego de volver a ejecutar el programa pero estaba vacío.

### ¿Que implica abrir un archivo com `"w"`?

Si lees la tabla que proporciona la referencia de [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) en la documentación, verás que `"w"` abre el archivo y lo limpia al instante.

> open for writing, truncating the file first

Cuando vuelves a ejecutar el programa el archivo se limpia, por eso mismo no puedes ver nada. Puedes usar `"a"` que abre el archivo para escritura sin limpiar o puedes usar la linea `print(file.read())` para visualizar la lectura desde terminal.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido. Creo que ahora he entendido mejor los modos de open() que al parecer no me habían quedado claro. También, como dices, se me hace muy raro que tenga que vincular manualmente al directorio y no conozco la causa de esto, pero al menos gracias a eso y a ti he aprendido algo nuevo.